# Add reciepents UI for mail application

Tags: jquery

Here's the script using jquery

```
$('#AddRecipents').click(function(e){
    $('#abcd').append("<input type='text' name='Recipents' size='29'>");
});
```

It is not creating new textfields.

Here is the HTML code inside `div` with id `abcd`.

```
<label for="Recipents">Enter Recipents</label>
<input type="text" name="Recipents" size="29">
<input type="button" name="AddRecipent" id="AddRecipent" value="Add Recipents">
```

The textfields are not showing in web page. Why?

Comment: You know your selector is wrong right? No elements exist with the ID `#AddRecipents`, it should be `#AddRecipent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will replace `#AddRecipents` with `#AddRecipent` it should work.

In HTML code, you don't have in presend an element with id `AddRecipents`.

Comment: Thnq fr the suggestion. indeed this was very silly but the actual mistake was i did not add 
$(document).ready

Answer (score 1):

You gave `id="AddRecipient"` to your html element, but you called it `AddRecipients` in your JS code